# In Shingeki No Kyojin, when does Eren lose 3 years of his memory?

Tags: attack-on-titan

I was just reading asks on Attack On Titan and came upon this one [What was Eren's vision about?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/13548/what-was-erens-vision-about?rq=1)

Where someone says in one of the answers that Eren lost three years of his memory due to his father experimenting on him? Can anyone tell me what volume of the manga this is from because I am all caught up and I don't remember this. I thought the timeline went like this (from the beginning of the manga/anime:

1. Dr.Jaeger says he's going into town to do some check ups
2. The wall is broken
3. The news reaches Dr.Jaeger (not sure how long this took)
4. He kills the real royal family
5. He goes after Eren (although I'm not sure how he found him??)
6. Injects Eren (like we saw in his flashbacks), Eren eats him and he dies.

I'm also not sure how old Eren was when he ate his Dad? I think maybe he was 12 or quite young. 
So in all this I don't remember his Dad doing any experiments on him or if was mentioned/explained/hinted anywhere?

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but I think number 4 happened before number 1. Wasn't the main reason the armored and giant titan attacked, was to locate the coordinate?

Comment: I don't know? I mean that would make sense but then why did Eren have visions of his Dad _after_ his Dad disappeared? And I guess it could be 4 then 1 because he got all mysterious about what was in the basement before he left. Would this also not mean that his dad would've injected him before the wall was broken, if the reason the wall was broken was to find Eren? haha I hope all this becomes more clear as the manga and anime go on! :)

Answer (score 2):

From the manga and from the anime I don't remember Eren losing 3 years of his memory. From your timeline I think your pretty accurate, except that I would switch 3 and 4 around, as I think that Eren's dad went deeper into the wall to kill the real royal family.[Chapter 1, page 44] He killed the royal family by turning into a titan. Therefore I think it was only after he turned back to a human that he headed back to his home when the news of wall Maria fallen reach Dr. Jaeger.[[Chapter 62, page 19-24]][1] He probably then starts looking for Eren in every camp (where the survivors of wall Maria stay) there is to find Eren. As the royal family is looking for him, he needs to disappear. To do so and still fulfill his goal he injects a drug into Eren who eats his dad and gains Titan powers alongside the "coordinate".[Chapter 3, page 21 ] [[Chapter 10, page 32-35]][2]

Edit:
The only part I don't quite get is when Eren says to his dad "You've been acting weird ever since mom died"[Chapter 3, page 21]. It's the only time where it looks like Eren has seen his dad after the fall of wall Maria and before he turned into a titan, so that might be an indicator of a 3 year void in Eren's memory, even though this would be just speculation.

Comment: Could you link some sources that back this answer up.

Comment: I'm not able to add more links to the sources, as I don't have enough reputations

Comment: Actually chapter 3 makes sense. You should read chapter 71 again from page 33-ish, where the news of the broken wall Maria gets out. There we see how Grisha hears about the fall of wall Maria when the Giant Titan attacked. He searches for his son, and hears Carla died. Then he takes Eren into the forest to *experiment* on him aka turn him into a Titan. So to me it looks like the chain of events is 1. Grisha goes into wall Rose to kill the royal family. 2. He kills the royal family. 3. The wall falls. 4. He meets Eren right after and gives him the Coordinate.

Comment: Off-topic, welcome to the Anime and Manga Stackexchange, I hope you enjoy it here. If you have questions, feel free to ask in the comment section and once you have [enough reputation](http://anime.stackexchange.com/privileges), feel free to join the community in the chat room. As a tip, you aren't it is best not to link to external images, because they might be taken down, the hyperlink might change (and we aren't fond of linking to illegal sources), so use the image button instead. That way, pictures get re-uploaded to imgur, with which SE has special arrangements to keep them up.

Comment: @PeterRaeves thank you for your input. I will keep this in mind and also re-read chapter 71