# Why did Eren have a flashback about titans in episode 1?

Tags: attack-on-titan

For those who have finished Attack on Titan season one: If you take all that you know into account and rewatch the first episode up to the the first 3 minutes, you will see that Eren was dreaming about the titans before he had ever met one. Do you think that Eren can live in another world or subconsciousness? Is there any explanation for him seeing this dream?

Comment: Well, this has been explained in the manga, but a lot will be spoiled by explaining. Are you sure you want to know the answer already?

Comment: Related? http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/13548/2604

Comment: @Maroon Might even be a duplicate.

Comment: @PeterRaeves I didn't know there was a manga about Attack on Titan. I didn't do that much research etc. So if I get it right the anime is based on the manga? Then I would like to know if the manga you read is already finished and if the story of the manga and the anime are the same. Thanks, my post is indeed a duplicate, should I delete mine or is it oke to keep it?

Comment: @GinSin The anime is indeed based on the manga, so the story is the same. To give you an idea how far ahead the manga is, the anime is based on chapters 1 to 33 and there are 74 chapters now, each containing about 40 pages. It isn't finished though and there are only monthly chapters coming out. So it might be frustrating to wait for new chapters. If you prefer watching the anime, then you could just wait a little longer as season 2 will be released next year. You shouldn't delete yours, we will link both together, so don't worry about that.