# Why did Historia see her father's memories?

Tags: attack-on-titan

In **Season 3 Episode 9** we see that

> after slaying her own father, Historia gains access to his memories.
>
>  [image: 1]]

According to **Season 3 Episode 6** and **Chapter 89**,

> titan shifters are able to see the memories of their past and future holders. (read [here](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/39431/32704) for explanation)

Historia, however,

> has, up to this point, never possessed the power of the titans.

But we do know from **Season 2 Episode 5** and **Season 3 Episode 2** that

> she has blue blood which means she can use the Founding Titan's abilities to its full potential. (not exactly full, but at least more than Eren)

---

Is there an explanation for this?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, it was never discussed as of the release of the most recent chapter. That specific scene in **Chapter 68** was mostly what happened in the anime. It could be explained in a future chapter. 
Looking closely at **Episode 9**,

> it can be seen that after the flashbacks of her father's memories, Historia opens her eyes as if surprised at what she saw. This might mean that her eyes were closed during the flashback scenes, implying that she saw her father's memories.

In the manga, this was not exactly what happened.

> She just widens her eyes and opens her mouth slightly as he killed him and as her father's memories were shown. From my interpretation, it could be that she was just surprised at what she had done.

Comment: That's too bad. I've rewatched the episode, reread that chapter, and noticed the difference you pointed out. So are you saying that in the anime it is a _flashback_, but in the manga it is just an _information_ for the reader?

Comment: Yeah. Assuming otherwise would go against the fact you mentioned regarding current titan shifters possessing memories of the past holders. His father was, first of all, not a titan shifter. To be able to have access to her father's memory, he must be a titan shifter and Historia must need to consume him and acquire the power herself. There is still a possibility that this is an unexplained power of those possessing blue blood, although the chances this will be further discussed in the manga are low, seeing how far it is in the story.

Comment: I dunno. If you ask me, they're both _flashbacks_. I admit that Historia doesn't close her eyes in the manga, but I think this is just an _artistic choice_. I still hope Isayama will resolve this one day because that scene in episode 9 stood out way too much.

Comment: Yes, they are both flashbacks. Sorry for the confusion. What I'm saying is that Historia did not necessarily see them. Having flashbacks in a manga does not necessarily require that a character is experiencing them. They could be for the reader's benefit. Killing your own father is enough to have someone make a shocked expression. For all we know, they could also be his father's flashbacks seeing as it was her father's body she cut. Remember that thing they always mention in any movies or books where when someone's about to be killed their 'life flashes before their eyes'?

Comment: Okay, now I get what you're saying. You do have a point. I'm not sure what to think of it now, though. Did Historia see the memories or did she not? Well, the way it is presented in the manga (Historia's eyes wide open; Rod's memories placed all around her head) implies to me that she actually _does_ see them. However, you're interpretation also makes sense.